# Outlook 2010 Rules for BCC

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

We have a user trying to setup a rule in Outlook to automate BCC'ing individuals when emails are sent from an account.

After digging through the rule setup screens, it seems like Outlook only allows you to configure CC recipients but BCC is not even an option.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hej, you need to enable Developer ribbon from Outlook Options and then write/use VBA script which fill in BCc for you.

[See this article for details.](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/how-to-automatically-bcc-in-outlook-2010/)

Comment: Sorry, do you have any references /code snippets I can refer to? Writing macros in Outlook is a new concept to me. Much appreciated.

Comment: If I correctly understand you, this is what you need > [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736.aspx)